# How to secure .evn file in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have make a Laravel 5.8 project In which many API are make for android APP.
And one user find a bug his using our app and get some error. It shows the code of the .evn file. so how to secure .evn file to get any error.

Comment: A Laravel error does not show any code if the application is in production mode. set `APP_ENV` to `production` and `APP_DEBUG` to `false`.

Comment: First you should use the `production` environment and second make sure, that your `.env` is not shipped public by your webserver.

Answer (score 0):

change .env in
this `APP_DEBUG=true`
to `APP_DEBUG=false`

Comment: this answer was flagged for low quality, please better the answer with more supporting info and an explanation